# Google Oauth refresh_token invalid_grant

Tags: python, google-oauth

I wrote a small app to clean out errors in Google's Search Console (formally Google Webmaster Tools) using Oauth to connect accounts. This was running fine for the past two weeks, however, today I have noticed the the following error:

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/graingerkid/search_console_auto/scripts/error_count.py", line 97, in <module>
    get_error_stats()
  File "/home/graingerkid/search_console_auto/scripts/error_count.py", line 19, in get_error_stats
    access_token = get_refreshed_tokens(refresh_token)
  File "/home/graingerkid/search_console_auto/scripts/refresh_token.py", line 25, in get_refreshed_tokens
    access_token = keys['access_token']
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

After investigating and trying to debug my code I realised I was not getting an `access_token` when requesting one with the `refresh_token`, here is the output:

### Output

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Here is the function I wrote to grab the `access_tokens` (I've changed sensitive info):

### Code

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import json
import httplib2
import urllib
import pprint


def get_refreshed_tokens(refresh_token):
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = '98997543650-f0tn93u86vmts4j2m987654359shue6gu9g.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'TFGZVLVG7VtnnrbNDTYFNBRgbfdFuENkBY'

    h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
    url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    body = {
        'client_secret': GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'client_id': GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
      }
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'}
    response, content = h.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))

    print content
    keys = json.loads(content)

    try:
        access_token = keys['access_token']
    except Exception as e:
        pass

        access_token = None

    return access_token

get_refreshed_tokens('1/lWS6Fu3Hz5dMBPk9huVu6mt5yrnj5hrunhMEf7vs_UdibrBactUREZofsF9C7PrpE-j')
```

When requesting access to a users account I use the following:

```
google = oauth.remote_app('google',
                          base_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/',
                          authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
                          request_token_url=None,
                          request_token_params={'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                                                'response_type': 'code',
                                                'access_type':'offline',
                                                'approval_prompt':'force'},
                          access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                          access_token_method='POST',
                          access_token_params={'grant_type': 'authorization_code'},
                          consumer_key=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                          consumer_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
```

Bearing in mind this worked fine for several weeks, I'm struggling to understand what's gone wrong, and searches on SO have not yielded answers.

Can anyone help with this?

(the accounts connected to these are mine, I have checked their access and the API access in Google API console is still intact, nothing has changed.)

Comment: check the time on the machine this code is running on.  Your server’s clock is not in sync with NTP.